# How to build and run c++ programs in Sublime Text 2, Windows 8?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, build-process, sublimetext2

I installed Codeblocks with mingw, chose default compiler, and could build and run a simple hello program without errors.

I installed Sublime Text 2, copy pasted the same hello world program:

```
// my first program in C++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Upon building, I get the error message:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ '' -o '/' && '/'"]]
[dir:  C:\Windows\system32]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\]
[Finished]
```

What do I need to do in order to build and run a simple program using Sublime Text 2?

Comment: `bash` and `g++` are typically unix programs (I'm not 100% sure if MingW calls its version `gcc`/`g++`. So it seems that you will need some configuring to make it work on windows.

Comment: Try adding `C:\MinGw\msys\1.0\bin` (where `bash.exe` resides, if it's true for your installation) to system path (Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environmental Variables and add the bash path to %PATH% in System variables.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @EarlGray My MinGW installation folder is inside the Codeblocks folder, and there isn't a msys folder there. There is a bin folder, but it does not contain bash.exe. Any other ideas?

Comment: I installed g++/gcc and it included a bash file. I then added the path to that folder like you said. Upon building hello world, I get a new error message: g++: : No such file or directory
g++: No input files
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure you **save the file** you're working on, wherever on your drive, before building and running.

Sublime Text 2 needs g++, bash, etc in order to compile. These packages need to be installed on your computer, as per the instructions on this page:

http://mjiang.com/mec/cs244/files/Installing%20c++_g++_on_Windows.pdf

Comment: Sublime text is a text editor, though its quite awesome, but not a compiler. The programs you are trying to run are UNIX programs. So I assume, you have to be either using cygwin(A program which creates UNIX environment inside windows) or switch to Linux altogether. It may sound daunting, but I strongly encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 4):

**For WINDOWS:**

If you have Dev C++ (Bloodshed) then,

OPEN **SUBLIME TEXT 2** and creat a new file to write your code (change build system to c++ through `Tools> Build System> C++` as **SublimeText2** doesn't come with `build-system for c`)

After that, you save that file to `bin` folder contained in `Dev-Cpp` folder and press `ctrl+b`

If your code is correct (bug free) then you'll found a corresponding file (in `.exe` format) on same directory which will show you

> Hello World!

***REMEMBER: SUBLIME TEXT 2 is an Editor, not a COMPILER***

Answer (score 4):

You could use my working C++.sublime-build file for Windows:
https://gist.github.com/trietptm/4950038

Answer (score 1):

just create new Build-system (TOOLS->BUILD SYSTEM->NEW BUILD SYSTEM)

```
{
"windows":
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall", "&","start", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
},
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

and save it as (name_you_can_provide).sublime-build and use that build system. :)

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you already have installed MingW in your computer.)

You need to go to 
**Preferences->Browse Packages->C++ folder->C++.sublime-build;**
bring this **C++.sublime build** file into the sublime text editor and now paste this code :

```
{ "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"], "selector": "source.c++", "working_dir": "$file_path", "variants": [ { "name": "Run", "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "$file_path/$file_base_name"], "shell": true } ]
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You must install MinGW, then add path to MinGW to PATH variable.