# Setting up Sublime text 2 with c++

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I want to get started with c++, but I am not sure how to setup sublime text 2 to run c++. If anyone knows how, that would be great!

Comment: Just write your code, then compile it?

Comment: AFAIK, it should just work if it can find GCC. Of course there are a lot of adjustments you can make, but still.

Comment: No, when I put this code in:

Comment: sorry tried to edit it, but i couldn't put the error in

Comment: My OS is windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text is just a code editor, not an IDE. As such, it cannot compile code; you will need a separate compiler to compile C++. However, I do believe sublime can be configured to compile your code with an an external compiler and run it in the sublime prompt.

Comment: Where would I find an external compiler and then use it to run c++? unlike python (Which you can just download) c++ doesn't have a download.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Comment: Do I need to download it?

Comment: It also says: Important: because these are source releases, they will be of little use to you if you do not already have a C compiler on your machine.

Comment: I do not have a c compiler

Comment: @jason97931 Have a look at [MinGW](http://mingw.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a compiler. Sublime text is only a *text editor*.

I recommend [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Follow the instructions onsite, download and install. Make sure to install the C++ package and set PATH in your environment variables.

Test this by using `g++` in cmd. If you do not get a "not recognized as a command error", you have set it up correctly.

By default, Ctr + B in Sublime Text compiles the code with `g++`.

Comment: And how do I use g++ in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, Sublime text is used as a code editor, which you can set the language in the View tab I believe. This post has answers which explain how to install G++/C++ and how to use compile, then, from sublime text 2 : [How to build and run c++ programs in Sublime Text 2, Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145684/how-to-build-and-run-c-programs-in-sublime-text-2-windows-8)