# sublime text doesn't proceed my code after cin. what should I do?

Tags: c++

all

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm currently teaching myself C++ with sublime text editor. I'm having a problem where the code does not proceed after I input something through cin. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string password = "password";
  cout << "Enter your password: " << flush;

  string input;
  cin >> input;

  if(input == password) {
    cout << "Password accepted." << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Access denied." << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After I put my input, it doesn't cout anything such as "password accepted" or "access denied". Does anyone know how to solve this problem and make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run that program from the terminal?

Comment: I can tell you that the code compiles on c++ shell (http://cpp.sh/7g26n). But please don't compare strings like that, the only reason that might work is because of string pooling. Use if (input.compare(password) == 0) instead.

Comment: @JulianDeclercq String comparison in C++ using the `operator==` function overload for `std::string` is perfectly fine. You seem to be thinking about Java.

Comment: After you input your "password", you *do* press the enter key? That's is what causes the terminal program to actually "send" the input to the process.

Comment: Have you looked at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145684/how-to-build-and-run-c-programs-in-sublime-text-2-windows-8

Comment: Lastly, what does this have to do with the text editor you are using? Sublime Text is not an [Integrated Development Environment (IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). If you configure it to actually build and run your program, it's still not Sublime Text that runs your program, it creates a terminal window with a shell that does it for you.

Comment: This program works fine on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned your code does work as expected.

The issue is when you build a c++ program in sublime text it will compile that file and then run. What you see is sublime text piping the output from your program back to a window within sublime text.

Sublime does not have the ability to send input back to your program. Hence why your program "does not proceed after I input something through cin". There are some plugins available on the linux version of sublime that give access to a full terminal emulator, I have not tried using one of these but they do exist.

What I would recommend is that you learn how to use the gnu tool chain using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but since I faced the same problem and this was the first page to pop up when I searched for it, I'll post the solution I think best for other newbros (Does this term work outside of Eve online? Who knows...).

Do remember I am new as well and what I am saying is probably the wrong approach and bad for you, but it will get you started....

**Option 1:** Use Sublime text to edit and run the file on terminal as everyone suggests. After the first few times it gets extremely repetitive and annoying. As long as you know how to do it, you should be fine. NOT RECOMMENDED.

**Option 2:** Use VS Code or other IDEs. The problem with this one is that sublime text is just faster to start which is primarily why I like subl. In all honesty VS code is also fast and responsive and I think switching to it is not at all a bad idea.

**Option 3:** If you still wanna continue using Sublime text. Set it up for something they call competitive programming. Skip the 'bits/stdc++.h' part and do everything else. Follow this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setting-up-sublime-text-for-cpp-competitive-programming-environment/

*In the rare event this webpage stops existing in the future:*

**Step 1:** Have mingw/mingw64 compiler installed and added to path. (You will find plenty of resources that will help you with that).

**Step 2:**

- (i) Open Sublime Text editor and then go to **Tools > Build System > New Build System**.
- (ii) Paste the following code in the file and save it.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
            "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
            "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.out"],
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir":"$file_path",
    "selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

- (iii) Name the file as “CP.sublime-build“ (or anything really, just name something you know so that you can find it from the **Tools > Build system list**. Also make sure to keep the '.sublime-build' part.)

**Step 3:** Create these three new files and save them in the same folder. (Keep it somewhere where you store your codes or something like that).

*file.cpp:* The file for writing the code.

*inputf.in:* The file where we will be giving the input.

*outputf.out*: The file where the output will be displayed.

**//Also don't change the names of these files since this is part of the code we had earlier.**

**Step 4:** Setting up Window layout:

-Select **View > Layout > Columns : 3**. This will create three columns in the workspace. Move the three files into three columns.

-Select **View > Groups > Max Columns : 2**.

-Select the build system we just created from **Tools > Build System > CP** (or whatever you named it).

This will create a live environment for you write and run/test code at the same time in subl. o7

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in Submlime is to create a new Build System.

1. Goto Tools > Build System > New Build System..
2. Paste something like below into the open file and save it.

   `{
   "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && open -a Terminal.app '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }`

   *This is for Mac OSX, you will have the change it for your environment.
3. Change Build System to saved name

When you build next time, there will be a new Terminal App window waiting for the cin input.